# Dataframe set_index function returning error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing

I have a dataframe and am trying to set the index to the column 'JnlNo'. Currently the index is just a row number. The JnlNo are integers. But it keeps returning this error:

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_52996/1782638178.py in 
----> 1 journals=journals.set_index('JnlNo')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
312
313         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
5449
5450         if missing:
-> 5451             raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
5452
5453         if inplace:

KeyError: "None of ['JnlNo'] are in the columns"

I have initially ran these codes
import pandas as pd
journals = pd.read_csv('Journals.csv')
journals.head()

but when I then went ahead to set_index
journals=journals.set_index('JnlNo'), it returned the error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `journals.columns`. You can only use columns that are in the DataFrame. `JnlNo` is not in the dataframe as the error message tells you. Maybe you're confusing an uppercase i with a lowercase L or something like that.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your answer. I have used journals.columns to check if 'JnlNo is in the DataFrame and it returns JnlNo as one of the columns in the DataFrame. But I am not sure why I cant set the index to JnlNo

Comment: Have you checked the spelling? That would be my only suspicion. If `JnlNo` is actually in the dataframe, it should work. Try something like this:`name = "JnlNo"; assert name in journals.columns, f"{name} is not in the dataframe";`